# Sending SMS to multi device

Tags: android

This is My code to send SMS for multi devices. But the SMS is sent to only first number four times. I want to send SMS to all user stored in ArrrayList.

```
public class SendSMSActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonSend;

    String smsBody = "Message from the API";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSend);
    textPhoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
    textSMS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

    final ArrayList <String> phone=new ArrayList<String>();
    phone.add("9742504034");
    phone.add("9535179695");
    phone.add("9742504034");
    phone.add("7204860021");

    buttonSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {



        try {

            for(int i = 0; i < phone.size(); i++)
            {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

            smsManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(phone), null, smsBody, null, null);


            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }



        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "SMS faild, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
           }

        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: please learn some java's basics ... [`smsManager.sendTextMessage(String.valueOf(phone), ...)`](http://ideone.com/2I7FIu) <= this is not how we access array element ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your for loop should be as follows:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
for(String number: phone)
{        
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(number, null, smsBody, null, null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```